# Custom UITableViewCell not loading properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, tableview, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has two subviews, a label and a UIView. The UIView is meant to be a container for a custom view that will be loaded at runtime and it has a red background set in IB.

The custom cell has a method setupWithData(data: Data) that sets up the cell. This method is called from tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) with the data from the tableView's data source.

However, when the tableView is loaded, only the red backgrounds of the first few cells are seen (without the custom view). When I scroll down, the custom views start to appear. Oddly enough, the labels for all the cells all have the correct text.

I investigated using the interface debugger and found out that the custom view does get added to the container view but all its constraints (width, height, midX, midY) are set to 0. In addition, I also looked at the loaded cells after I scrolled down (the ones that have actually been properly loaded with my custom view) and realized that sometimes the container views in will sometimes have two subviews of my custom view with different data.

I would appreciate any help regarding this.

N.B.: I am using Swift 3.

**Update**

Here's my `setup` code:

```
func setupWithParticle(_ particle: ParticleProtocol, isFavourite: Bool = false) {
    self.particleLabel.text = particle.name(withColor: false)

    let particleView = ParticleView(position: CGPoint.zero, width: self.particleViewContainer.width, particle: particle)
    particleView.respondsToTouch = false
    particleView.setBorders([.Top, .Left, .Right, .Bottom], width: 1, color: .black())

    if isFavourite {
        particleView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9559464455, green: 0.7389599085, blue: 0.2778314948, alpha: 1)
    }

    self.particleViewContainer.subviews.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    self.particleViewContainer.addSubview(particleView)
}
```

Comment: Please put your setupWithData stuff. We can't imagine without code what you did.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh updated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `addSubview:` in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Remember that cell is reusable. `particleView` will be added to your cell over and over again.

So please try to remove subview from `particleViewContainer` before you `addSubview:` to it

**UPDATE**

Try to call `self.parentViewContainer.layoutIfNeeded()` before you use `self.parentViewContainer.width`.

Comment: I'm afraid removing subviews only helps with the presence of multiple custom views in the container.

You said to not call `addSubview` in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, where should I call it then?

Comment: You can call addSubview: in cellfor if you remove subview correctly.

Comment: I do that now (through `setupWithParticle`) but my problem is not fixed. I still see the red background of the container view initially before scrolling.

Comment: Can you update your code in setupWithParticle to your post?

Comment: Make a breakpoint in setup and see if self.parentViewContainer.width is equal to 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118102/discussion-between-youssef-sami-and-user3480295).

Comment: Sorry, I am going to sleep. It's 3 a.m now. Maybe tomorrow.